# Where is the original file for the default Contacts profile picture located?

Tags: macos, contacts

I'm trying to find where this icon is located. I've looked through `/Applications/Contacts.app`'s `Assets.car` file and it wasn't in there. I've also looked through `/System/Library/CoreServices/C­oreTypes.bundle` and it's not in there either, though the base "human" image is in there, albeit in black.

Where might it be located?
[image: profile picture]

Comment: `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources` See this

Comment: @ankiiiiiii The only images in that folder are ones I've added to contacts.

Answer (score 1):

The file is located in many, many different car files. Below is one of the car's and one pdf.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContactsUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Assets.car
/System/Library/Frameworks/ContactsUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/silhouette_placeholder.pdf
```

Inside the car files there are black silhouette pdfs. My guess is that inverts it (to white) and then adds the background.

[image]

[Heres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZIr0.png) my attempt at recreating it:

[image]