# Where's the iMessage contact icon stored?

Tags: messages, macos

Where is this empty avatar

[image]

stored on 
macOS Catalina?

Comment: [where-is-the-original-file-for-the-default-contacts-profile-picture-located](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365412/where-is-the-original-file-for-the-default-contacts-profile-picture-located)

Comment: Is  newly created avatar applicable here? or do we have something else?

Comment: Yeah that's fine

Comment: The other one was asked first so I answered there and linked this as dup